# How to select one of table A based on table B in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables Items and ItemDescriptions

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item_description.id'))

class ItemDescription(Base):
   __tablename__ = "item_description"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Given a list of ItemDescriptions I want a list of Items such that there is one item of each ItemDescription id. I don't care which item.

**[Edited for clarity]**

Given this list of item and descriptions:

```
Item, Description
1   , 1
2   , 1
3   , 1
4   , 2
5   , 2
6   , 3
7   , 3
8   , 3
```

I want a query that will return something like:

```
Item, Description
2   , 1
4   , 2
7   , 3
```

I'm having trouble working out the sub-queries etc.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big fan of column_property. Here's a way to do what you want with column_property:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item_description.id'))

class ItemDescription(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item_description'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    any_item_id = column_property(
        select(
            [Item.id],
            id == Item.description_id,
            limit=1,
        ).label('any_item_id'),
        deferred=True,
    )

e = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

descriptions = [
    ItemDescription(id=1),
    ItemDescription(id=2),
    ItemDescription(id=3),
]

s.add_all(descriptions)

items = [
    Item(id=1, description_id=1),
    Item(id=2, description_id=1),
    Item(id=3, description_id=1),
    Item(id=4, description_id=2),
    Item(id=5, description_id=2),
    Item(id=6, description_id=3),
    Item(id=7, description_id=3),
    Item(id=8, description_id=3),
]

s.add_all(items)

query = s.query(ItemDescription).options(undefer('any_item_id'))
for description in query:
    print description.any_item_id, description.id

# alternative way without using column_property
query = s.query(
    select(
        [Item.id],
        ItemDescription.id == Item.description_id,
        limit=1,
    ).label('any_item_id'),
    ItemDescription,
)
for item_id, description in query:
    print item_id, description.id
```

Comment: The column_property looks great, thank you! If I wanted to do this as a single query rather than the column property would I put the select in a subquery?

Comment: Yup, you can move the select into the query. I have added that to the answer. Personally, I still prefer column_property though :)

Comment: I like the column_query method but thank you for showing the in query way as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    description_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item_description.id'))
    desc = relationship(User, backref=backref('desc', order_by=id))

class ItemDescription(Base):
   __tablename__ = "item_description"
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

Now your every ItemDescription class will have an backref called `desc` which is nothing but a list of Item.

Now you can do something like this

item_desc = session.query(ItemDescription).\
...                        options(joinedload('desc').all()

for item in item_desc:
    print item.desc
```

I think this might not give you the exact answer. it will help i guess

Comment: Sorry, my explanation isn't very clear, I'll edit it to make clearer.